# No database selected php in oops

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am new to php.Kindly check the following code. I am getting No database selected error for the below code. I have written code in oops. Any help will be appreciated. Please help. I am getting error in this line

```
die("invalid".mysql_error());'
```

in runquery($query) method.

Dbconfig.php

```
<?php
class Dbconfig
{
     private $connection;

    public function __constructor($hostname,$username,$password,$database){

        $this->connection=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
        if(!$this->connection){
            die(mysql_error());
        }else{
            if(!mysql_select_db($database,$this->connection)){
                die(mysql_error());
            }

        }

    }

    function runQuery($query){
        $result= mysql_query($query);
        if($result){
            while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $resultset[]= $row;
            }
            if(!empty($resultset)){
                return $resultset;
            }
        } else {
            die("invalid".mysql_error());

        }
    }
}

?>
```

Config.php

```
<?php
require("path to dbconfig.php");
$base="http://localhost/slvbilling/";
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';
$database='slv';
$connect = new Dbconfig($hostname,$username,$password,$database);
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* is depreciated in new version and removed in 7.0. Please look into mysqli_* or PDO APIs.

Comment: Maybe this `require("path to dbconfig.php");` is the problem?

Comment: yes please use `mysqli_*`. you have made mistake in define constructor. it should be `public function __construct($hostname,$username,$password,$database)` instead `public function __constructor($hostname,$username,$password,$database)`

Comment: constructor will be define as `__construct` not as `__constructor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with below code in Dbconfig.php file

```
 <?php
    class Dbconfig
    {
         private $connection;

        public function __construct($hostname,$username,$password,$database){
        $this->connection=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
        if(!$this->connection){
            die(mysql_error());
        }else{
            if(!mysql_select_db($database,$this->connection)){
                die(mysql_error());
            }

        }

    }

    function runQuery($query){
        $result= mysql_query($query);
        if($result){
            while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $resultset[]= $row;
            }
            if(!empty($resultset)){
                return $resultset;
            }
        } else {
            die("invalid".mysql_error());

        }
    }
}

?>
```

its about Constructor only try above code it may help!

Answer (score 1):

Placed `or die(mysql_error())` with mysql function instead of placing redundant conditions.

Please try with below code..

```
<?php
class Dbconfig
{
     private $connection;

    public function __construct($hostname,$username,$password,$database){

        $this->connection=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($database,$this->connection))or die(mysql_error());
    }

    function runQuery($query){
        $result= mysql_query($query)or die("invalid".mysql_error());
        if($result){
            while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $resultset[]= $row;
            }
            if(!empty($resultset)){
                return $resultset;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with passing the connection to mysql_query:

```
 function runQuery($query){
     $result= mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
 .....
```

it should work without passing the connection but depending on the rest of the code in your project and the instances of the Database you are creating this might be the problem.

If you provide the code that is calling runQuery it would be easier for a correct answer.